# Find top n places that close to a route

Tags: geolocation, distance, openstreetmap

I have lots of places data(tourist attractions) stored in database. Every place has coordination info, such as latitude and longitude. When I randomly choose a route (for example: from somewhere in New York to somewhere in Boston), how can I find the 10 closest places along the route? I guess it's relative to geography algorithms. I'm trying to find a way to minimize the total calculation time and save cell phone battery. Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Show us some effort and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst   I just start building the app today and realize the problem. I'm still a student, have no map-develop experience before. The only solution I can come out is maybe 2d tree. Thats why I hope someone can show me some directions to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be:

- Consider the map to be a grid eg of 1km x1km boxes
- plot the route and see which of these grid boxes it enters.
- for each box, find the places/landmarks in the box which is not computationally expensive if you search your database my min/max longitude/latidtude position where the grid box starts/ends

To show the top N from these, you can calculate the shortest distance for these subset of places rather than the whole dataset.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very detailed solutions. I will try my best to implement it. Meanwhile I will wait a few days before voting for the best answer. thanks!

Comment: I will, once I have 15 reputations or more. Cheers : )